# Add interface methods dynamically

Tags: typescript

I would like to dynamically add methods defined in the interface. I thought the index signature would be the way to go, but sadly not all methods fit the same signature. My goal is to keep all type information.

Basic code, which currently doesn't compile because not all methods are implemented. When I add `Partial` the code compiles but I seem to lose type information.

```js
import anotherLib from "anotherLib";

interface IALotOfMethods<T> {
  methodA(): T;
  methodB(opts: MyOpts): T;
  ...
}

interface IMyClass<T> extends IALotOfMethods<T> {
  getName(): string;
  getSomething(): number;
}

class MyClass implements IMyClass<MyClass> {
  results: any[] = [];

  getName(): string {
    return "A Name";
  }

  getSomething(): number {
    return 0;
  }
}

const aLotOfMethodsList = ['methodA', 'methodB', ...];

aLotOfMethodsList.forEach(funcName => {
  MyClass.prototype[funcName] = function(opts: any) {
    this.results.push(anotherLib[funcName](opts));
    return this;
  }
})

const myObj = new MyClass();
myObj.methodA(); // methodA should be available/autosuggested
```

Is this possible? Do I need to implement all methods manually even though they basically all look the same? Do I need to forgo type information?

thank you

Comment: The problem is you want to implements the interface to keep types, but not declare all the method on your interface ?

Comment: I defined them all in the interface (`IALotOfMethods`), but the compiler complains if I don't implement them all in the implementation (class).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution that is also used [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6413) would be using class and interface merging with optional properties.

```
interface Component {
   optionalMethod?(l: GetLocalization): void;
}
abstract class Component {
    public abstract mustImplement(): void;
}

class Post extends Component {
    public mustImplement(): void {}
}
```

in your case : [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/haw1jv)

The auto complete works, but you might have a "can't call an undefined method" warning, so you must be sure of what you are doing

EDIT : Or even better without double merging

```
import anotherLib from "anotherLib";

abstract class Component<T> {
    methodA?(): T;
    methodB?(opts: string): T;
    public abstract mustImplement(): void;
}

class Post extends Component<string> {
    public mustImplement(): void {
    }
}

const aLotOfMethodsList = ['methodA', 'methodB'];

aLotOfMethodsList.forEach(funcName => {
  (Post as any).prototype[funcName] = function(opts: any) {
    this.results.push(anotherLib[funcName](opts));
    return this;
  }
})

const myObj = new Post();
myObj.methodA(); // autocomplete
```

Comment: Thanks, going to look init it. I saw something similar, what gets me here is that the interface and the abstract class have the same name. Should auto complete for the methods of the interface work?

Comment: they must have the same name for the merging to works. you can also make 2 abstract class with different name, and make the one with the non optional methods extends the one with optional method (and the name can differ). 

But I personally do not like that much that level of complexity for this (including the prototype forEach).

Comment: I was just surprised that this doesn't produce a conflict. I kept the merging since these two things come from different places, but everything seems to work. thanks